# Riemann integrability on open subset of $\mathbb{R}$

Tags: real-analysis, improper-integrals, riemann-integration

Let $f:\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}$ be a continuous function such that $f$ is Riemann integrable over $\mathbb{R}$.

Is it true that $f$ is Riemann integrable over any open subset $A\subset \mathbb{R}$??

Comment: What do you mean by $f$ is Riemann integrable over $\mathbb{R}$? You might find your answer there.

Comment: What is your definition of integrable?

Comment: I mean improper integral as defined here https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Improper_integral

Comment: A function which has an improper integral restricts to an integrable function on any *closed* interval, and thus restricts to an integrable function on a closed interval that contains $A$, but as RRL points out this may not work for open intervals depending on how you define the integral.

Comment: I understand. But It works on open subsets whose boundary have measure zero like $(0,+\infty)$, right?

Comment: True as long as you are talking about an improper integral on $(0,+\infty)$ not the Riemann integral.

Answer (score 4):

Assuming you mean Riemann integrable on any closed, bounded interval and you have defined the Riemann integral over an arbitrary open set using the characteristic function, the answer is no.

We can construct an open set $A \subset [0,1]$ whose boundary does not have measure zero. Take $f(x) = 1$.

Then the Riemann integral

$$\int_A f := \int_0^1 f(x) \chi_A(x) \, dx $$

does not exist

**Construction of $A$**

Let $\{r_i\}$ be an enumeration of the rational numbers in $(0,1)$. This is a countable set. We can take intervals such that $r_i \in(a_i,b_i) \subset (0,1)$ and $\sum_{i \geqslant1} (b_i - a_i) < 1$.  The union

$$A = \bigcup_{i \geqslant 1}(a_i,b_i)$$

is an open set with boundary $\partial A= [0,1] \setminus A$ since the rationals are dense in $[0,1]$. However, $m(\partial A) = m([0,1]) - m(A) > 1 - \sum_{i \geqslant 1}(b_i-a_i)> 0$.

Comment: This is interesting, care to elaborate? Namely, how do you construct such an open set, and how do you show that the Riemann integral does not exist?

Comment: See Spivak, Calculus on Manifolds, problem 3-11 where a non-rectifiable set in $\mathbb{R}$ is constructed. Then the characteristic function is discontinuous on a set of non-zero measure so it is not Riemann integrable.

Comment: In $\mathbb{R}^n$ where $n$ may be $1$, Riemann integrals are defined on rectangles (intervals) first and then exptended to arbitrary sets using the characteristic function.  If the boundary is not of measure $0$, then the integral will not exist unless the function approaches $0$ at every boundary point -- and this can't happen for the function $f(x) = 1$.

Comment: Perhaps a better way to define the integral over such an open set would be to take a limit of integrals over unions of closed intervals contained in the open set. Would not the limit be defined in this case, or would this fail for similar reasons?

Comment: @MonstrousMoonshiner: That is how an improper Riemann integral over an open set in $A \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ can be defined. It requires that the function be Riemann integrable over those closed subintervals.  But existence of an improper integral does not mean the function--  in this case $\chi_A$ -- is Riemann integrable over $A$. I will elaborate in the anser about the construction of this pathological set $A$.

Comment: See also "fat Cantor set".

Comment: In fact I have seen fat Cantor sets; it just didn't occur to me that they could provide the sort of counterexample necessary here. I've even seen the example you mentioned in the update before, but that one didn't occur to me either. Real analysis is weird.

Comment: Curious to know your comment on theorem 3.2 in this [paper](http://marathwadamathsociety.org/vol14-1/6june13divate1.pdf)

Comment: @TonyPiccolo: The above construction of an open subset of $[0,1]$ that is not rectifiable is a standard example found in Munkres, Spivak, etc.  The characteristic function of this set is not Riemann integrable.  It is constructed as a union of countably many intervals that overlap.  However as an open set in $\mathbb{R}$ it must also be a countable union of pairwise disjoint intervals. It seems to contradict theorem 3.2,  asserting that the characteristic function of a countable union of pairwise disjoint intervals is discontinuous only at countably many endpoints -- hence, Riemann integrable.

Comment: I would say the theorem in the paper is incorrect -- missing such pathological examples of bounded open sets with boundaries of non-zero measure. Perhaps an analogous situation where intuition fails is the Cantor set which includes points like $1/4$ that are not endpoints of the countably many removed intervals.